# How to get the currently submitted value in a GET form

Tags: php, forms

I have a very simple GET form with one text field:

```
<form action="blah" method="get" name="blah" onsubmit="blah">
  <input type="text" name="page" value="blah" />
</form>
```

What I want is to get the current submitted value from the url:

```
$page_value = $_REQUEST["page"];
```

but this will only get the previous submitted value, not the current one.

Comment: Notice that there's a difference between `current submitted value` to `current value`.

Comment: Yes, the current value is actually the previously submitted one. But I need the currently submitted one. I guess I will have to do it with javascript.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by the `previous submitted value` - do you mean the one you see on the URL when you submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="blah" name="blah" onsubmit="blah">
  <input type="text" name="page" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['page'])?>" />
</form>
```