# JS - read value of submitted form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

If one submits a GET form, the resulting address will look like `www.example.com/stuff?param1=stuff&param2=morestuff`. I know how to read/set the value of a form field on a page, but how do I read submissions from the previous page (in the URL) with JavaScript? I guess I could take the url and `split()` it, to get the parameters, but is there any quicker/simpler way to read param1 (just an example)?

Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607851/how-to-get-the-currently-submitted-value-in-a-get-form), since that question is about how to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getQuerystring(key)

{
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,\\\]);

 var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");

 var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);

 if(qs != null)
     return(qs[1]);
 else
     return("");

}
```

Comment: I'm impressed how you and Iwo gave almost the same answer. Basically the same function that doesn't use `location.search`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no simple way to do that.

Use something like this:

```
var qstring = {}, src = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    var parts = src[i].split("=");
    qstring[unescape(parts[0])] = unescape(parts.slice(1).join("="));
}
```

Now the object `qstring` is a key/value map of the query string. Keep in mind that values with the same key are overwritten, so you may want to store them in an indexed array instead of an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) topic is answer to your question.

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

You can try also [this one](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

- **[jQuery URL Parser Plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)**. In case you want to use jQuery.
- **[jsUri](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/)**. In case jQuery is too heavy for you.

Comment: It's like killing a mosquito with a barrel gun...

Comment: @MaxArt Excuse me, maybe I'm stupid. But I don't understand?!!

Comment: That plugin does a lot more than parsing the query string. So Bluefire would load the whole jQuery framework, plus that plugin, for a task of a bunch of lines of code. Heavy.

Comment: @MaxArt you know what, maybe your'e right. I will edit my answer, there is also a tiny library that doesn't use jQuery. Thanks for that